# Is it possible to build a custom Npm build task using a different Node.js version using the hosted build server in Team Services?

Tags: azure-devops

The hosted agent / build server in Team Services comes with [a list of software](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/build/services/hosted-agent-pool#software). One the programs installed is Node.js version 0.12.7.

What I am wondering is:

Is it possible to build a custom task like the [Npm](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Npm) task that already exists as a first class task in Team Servies ([documentation here for how to write a custom task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks)) but instead using the newest Node.js 5.11.0 version instead of the old 0.12.7 one (dated 2014) which causes some npm install incompatibility issues?

If yes, is it as easy as taking the Npm task, tweak it to run Node.js 5.11.0 instead and then adding your custom Npm task to your build definition?

If no, what alternatives are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next update of the Hosted Build agents (coming in the next two weeks or so) will include an update to Node 5/npm 3.

Keep an eye on the Visual Studio Team Services Updates section of the [Visual Studio News page](https://www.visualstudio.com/news/news-overview-vs) for more details.

Edit 5/11: [This is happening now](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/05/11/hosted-build-pool-image-updates/).

Answer (score 2):

We also have a feature on our backlog to dynamically pull different tool installers at build time.  That also allows you to do things like run your build (test a lib etc...) against multiple versions of node.

It's early but here's the RFC:  https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/tools.md

Note, this won't run the full installers but will pull bits needed and pre-pended to the path.

So, what this will make possible is on the npm, gulp, etc... tasks, they could offer a node version picker with a set of popular ones precached on the image.

Answer (score 0):

No, the 5.11.0 version isn't installed in Hosted Build agent. The alternative way would be [deploy your own build agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/agents/windows). With your own build agent, you can install the software with the version you want.